# ListView - content of item taken from two different object lists

Tags: android, list, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I want to put into listview item information stored in two list. The problem is when I start to scroll, the btns which I didn't check, became highlighted and I think it's connected with recycler which is invoked when new view must be created.

This is how my code looks like:

lay of custom item view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:background="@color/kalendarz_frag_lay_child_row_separator"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/how_look_child_presecence_item_child_btn"
   android:layout_width="200dp"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@color/White"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView 
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/how_look_child_presecence_item_picture_of_child"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/child_avatar"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    ></ImageView> 

<com.example.kinder.TextViewWithFont
    android:id="@+id/how_look_child_presecence_item_name_surname_of_child"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:fontFamily="Lato-Reg.ttf"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>



 <LinearLayout 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="100dp"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:weightSum="11" >


<ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/how_look_child_presecence_item_obecny_but"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_obecny"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="@color/group_layout_item_back_match"

    />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/how_look_child_presecence_item_nieobecny_but"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_nieobecny" />

 <TextView android:id="@+id/how_look_child_presecence_item_absence_caused" 
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@color/group_layout_item_back_match"

    >

</TextView>
 </LinearLayout>


 </LinearLayout>
```

and this is my custom adapter

```
private class MyChildInitialAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ChildShortInfoClass> {


        public MyChildInitialAdapter() {
            // here we add some info which is needed to create ArrayAdapter here our custom
            //first the activity where it is 
            // second is exposition of product so how it will be look every single row 
            // it was created in product_exposition.lay
            // the third one is our List where we stored all items/object (containerOfProducts)
            super(getActivity(), R.layout.how_look_child_presecence_item, App_class.listOfChild );
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // to make smth with view we need to take it 
            View takenView = convertView;


            if(takenView == null)
            {                   
                takenView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.how_look_child_presecence_item, null, false);
            }
            // find the current object 
            final ChildShortInfoClass currentChild = App_class.listOfChild.get(position);               

            // layout of bio
            LinearLayout goToBioChildBtnLayout = (LinearLayout)takenView.findViewById(R.id.how_look_child_presecence_item_child_btn);
            // here we add click event to go to bio of child  
            goToBioChildBtnLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "child with id " +Integer.toString(currentChild.getId()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    ((MainScreen)getActivity()).showBioOfChoosenBaby(currentChild.getId()); 
                }
            });

            // here we would need to add text about child so name and surname 
            TextView childName = (TextView)takenView.findViewById(R.id.how_look_child_presecence_item_name_surname_of_child);

            childName.setText(currentChild.getNameString()+ " " + currentChild.getSurnameString());             

            // button present
            final ImageButton presentImageButton = (ImageButton)takenView.findViewById(R.id.how_look_child_presecence_item_obecny_but);

            // button unpresent
            final ImageButton unpresentImageButton = (ImageButton)takenView.findViewById(R.id.how_look_child_presecence_item_nieobecny_but);

            // if data is download we set values in our lay for btns
            // like some child is came to kindergarden or smth like 
            // that 
            if(App_class.ifDataAboutChildActivityIsDownloaded)
            {
                 ChildActivityDataClass currentChildActivityDataClass = null;
                for (ChildActivityDataClass item : App_class.listOfAcitvityDataOfChild) 
                {
                    if(item.getIdOfChild()==currentChild.getId())
                    {
                        currentChildActivityDataClass = item;
                    }

                }
                final ChildActivityDataClass takenOneActivityDataClass = currentChildActivityDataClass;




                // if is diferent then 0 it means that this activity is checked in db, 
                // so it means that we don't need to setonclicklistener we just indicate 
                // if the child is presence or not 

                if(takenOneActivityDataClass.presenceActivityDataValue.getIdOfState()!=0)
                {
                    if(takenOneActivityDataClass.presenceActivityDataValue.getIdOfState() == App_class.presenceObecny)
                    {
                        presentImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_obecny_active);
                        presentImageButton.setEnabled(false);
                        unpresentImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_nieobecny);
                        unpresentImageButton.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    else if (takenOneActivityDataClass.presenceActivityDataValue.getIdOfState() == App_class.presenceNieobecny) 
                    {
                        unpresentImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_nieobecny_active);
                        unpresentImageButton.setEnabled(false);
                        presentImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_obecny);
                        presentImageButton.setEnabled(false);
                    } 
                }       

                    // unpresnet button onClickListener
                    presentImageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) 
                        {                               
                                presentImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_obecny_active);
                                presentImageButton.setEnabled(false);
                                unpresentImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_nieobecny);
                                unpresentImageButton.setEnabled(false);
                                Log.i("clicked of id", "current child "+ Integer.toString(currentChild.getId())+
                                                        "currentChildActivityDataClass " + Integer.toString(takenOneActivityDataClass.getIdOfChild()));



                                ChangeTheActivityStatesInInternalList.changePresenceIdOfStateForParticularChild(currentChild.getId(), 15);

                        }
                    });                 

                    // unpresnet button onClickListener
                    unpresentImageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) 
                        {                               
                                unpresentImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_nieobecny_active);
                                unpresentImageButton.setEnabled(false);
                                presentImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_obecny);
                                presentImageButton.setEnabled(false);
                                Log.i("clicked of id", "current child "+ Integer.toString(currentChild.getId())+
                                        "currentChildActivityDataClass " + Integer.toString(takenOneActivityDataClass.getIdOfChild()));
                                ChangeTheActivityStatesInInternalList.changePresenceIdOfStateForParticularChild(currentChild.getId(), 16);

                        }
                    });                 
                }                   
            //}             
            return takenView;
        }
     }
```

Description of lists:

```
 App_class.listOfChild  - contain id of every child/ name / surname 
 App_class.listOfAcitvityDataOfChild - contain id of every child/ info if the first btn should be marked / info if the second btn should be marked
```

As I said the problem starts when I start scrolling, and it's connected that ArrayAdapter on scroll takes info from one list. Is there way to take info from two list to avoid problem with showing data on scroll ?

Comment: "I think it's connected with recycler" domyslam sie, ze chodzi o przyciski presentImageButton  i unpresentImageButton ...  tak ... dlatego musisz przywrócic przyciski do stanu pierwotnego w else dla  if(takenOneActivityDataClass.presenceActivityDataValue.getIdOfState()!=0) ... moim zdaniem i tak za dużo się dzieje w getView ...

Comment: did you tried setting buttons to android:focusable="false"
               android:focusableInTouchMode="false" 
which are being showed in listview ?

Comment: @Selvin Yeah, this is the answer. I was sure that if I set this default values in layout of my custom item view, it would be show this same way in the listview and I don't need to do any action in myCustomAdapter. Strange behavior imo

Comment: nope, it is not strange ... if convertView != null then you get the old view(coz it is more efficient than createing new one) ... with highlighted  buttons ... good resources to understand the ListView : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: Thx for this link, I will watch it. Make the answer from your comment and I would accept this

Comment: ide na obiad, nie mam czasu :P